# Unidentified Method 'id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to incorporate amistad (friendship gem) and I'm having some trouble.

Here is my controller for friendship create..

```
def create
invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
if current_user.invite invitee
  redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Successfully invited friend!"
else
  redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Sorry! You can't invite that user!"
end
end
```

I have current_user defined in a session helper (with help from Michael Hartl's tutorial) as

```
def current_user
remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
@current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

The error I am getting is pointing to this line of my controller

```
if current_user.invite invitee
```

and the error states undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

I have also tried changing the friendship controller's create action to

```
def create
invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @current_user.invite invitee
  redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Successfully invited friend!"
else
  redirect_to new_friend_path, :notice => "Sorry! You can't invite that user!"
end
end
```

Once I do that, it seems as though amistad's magic is forgotten, because 'invite' calls an undefined method error.

As you can tell, I'm pretty new to RoR and working on incorporating gems.

I'd appreciate any help getting this to work!
Thanks,
Peege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because, `current_user` method of SessionsHelper is not getting called instead `current_user` is treated as a local variable.

Add `include SessionsHelper` in your controller class. So, `current_user` method would be accessible to your controller.

**EDIT**

params[:id] is currently nil. Change the code as below:

```
 <%= link_to 'Add Friend', friends_path(id: @user.id), :method =>"post", class: "btn btn-default btn-success" %>
```

Comment: I added that in the friendship controller.  I still get the couldn't find user without ID error.  Could it be because I need to change the way the method is defined?  Thank you for your post!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm declaring the ID in the session helper. It is using remember tokens.

Comment: Don't change any other part of code. I hope you are trying with the  original code in question `invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:id])`

Comment: Yes, I've used with original:  invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @current_user.invite invitee --- with and without @.  Same error

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in this line:

```
invitee = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

post your create url, Before seeing your create request url.  I can only guess: maybe there isn't id parameter, please try:

```
invitee = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Comment: Sounds like you were right... Once I do that the error I get is Can't find user without ID...how do I pass an id..?